# How to connect to SQL developer using my own database

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm currently using SQL Developer 4.5.1.21 and want to take some time to learn language, run queries etc etc. I'm using a database that Oracle provides called "HR Schema" that is free for download. Now I know that I need to create a "connection" in order run queries onto this database. I begin running into trouble when I want to create my own connection. Can anybody walk me through the steps of creating a new connection? What I do is click the "+" button and click "new connection".

Comment: You say you are using a database called HR Schema. Have you actually installed Oracle and have a running instance of an Oracle database? Or did you just download the HR schema installation scripts? HR is just a schema (Tables, Packages, Functions, etc...) that is offered as a sample schema.

Comment: @gmiley I have sql developer and jdk. I am able to go into data modeler and load the "hr schema" database to look at the "hr relational model" however if I want to run queries I am instructed to make a "connection". I also am not allowed to connect to any oracle databases(I believe?) because I'm not paying for it.

Comment: You need to have an actual instance of Oracle server running. Do you have one of the following installed: `Oracle Database Personal Edition`, `Oracle Database Standard Edition`, or `Oracle Database Enterprise Edition`?

Comment: @gmiley I do not actually. As a student are these things that I am allowed to download and use for free?

Comment: Yes, Oracle offers a free version of their database, also your school should have student copies of various types of software. You should check with your professor. The free version of Oracle is `Oracle Express Edition`, but I do not know if the HR schema works with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem you have here is that you need to have an Oracle database instance installed before you can have something to connect to.

You have a couple of options here...

1. Download and use the free version of Oracle: `Oracle Express Edition`
2. You mentioned that you are a student. Check with your professor to see if they offer a more robust edition of Oracle for student use, such as:

   a. Oracle Personal Edition

   b. Oracle Standard Edition

   c. Oracle Enterprise Edition
3. If you have the available funds, and you intend on persuing a future in database work, you could purchase a license of one of the above mentioned editions.

You can read more about the various editions of Oracle [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/license.111/b28287/editions.htm#DBLIC110).

One thing to keep in mind here is that you are wanting to use the sample schemas that Oracle provides, in particular the "HR" schema. Taking a look at the [installation documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10831/installation.htm#COMSC001) over at the Oracle site, I do not see mention of the **Express** edition of Oracle server on the availability table, but that may not mean that it wont work.

To address the connection portion of your question, once you get your database set up and running, you should be able to connect to it by providing the hostname (`localhost` for connecting to your local machine), port, and various other information such as username and password. In all, your connection string would likely look like the following:

> Host=localhost; SID=MyOracleServer; port=1677; Min Pool Size=1;
>   Connection Lifetime=600; User ID=EhBabay; Password=secretpassword123;

Or within `SQL Developer` you should be able to connect to your local instance of the Oracle database fairly easily, without having to create a connection string. The connection string would still be used though, within any applications you write that you want to connect to the database with.

The main thing here, however is that you need to have an instance of an Oracle database installed and running somewhere that you have access to.

Comment: For whatever reason I cannot connect to my local instance. I use something like this: Connection Name: hr_test, Username: jmc7dt, Password:hr, I then hit save password, Hostname: localhost, Port: not sure what port I'm supposed to use since I looked at my ports on my mac and there are many, SID: Xe. When I hit test I get "Status : Failure -Test Failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection". What am I missing here?

Comment: @EhBabay All of this information you need for making a connection is something you should have configured while setting the oracle database up. I won't be able to tell you any of it as it is all configurable when you install your oracle database server.

Comment: I will try and figure out what's going on and will report my findings. Thanks again for the help.